# Files in httpSession

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I have requirement that need to store the uploaded files in session and send to the email. Is it possible to store the files inside session and can read it from it while sending email?ajaxfile upload is used to store the file objects into session for every upload.

Comment: You're going to be storing a lot of data in the session. Instead just store the fileName and when you need to send the email, retrieve the file and write it.

Comment: until then where do i persist the uploaded file?

Comment: I couldn't get you.do you have any sample?

Comment: I don't have a sample. When you upload the file to struts2, either you or the framework will write they bytes (from the file) it receives to some folder. Keep a reference to that file in the session. When you want to send the file in the email, just use the path of the file from the session to get it from the folder.

Comment: Yes. I see when i upload the file, the file is stored in server path."C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv02\upload". But i am not able to get the full path in the code to retrive the file again.

Comment: You should be able to get it from the request headers. I don't know which one.

Comment: Thank you. I will check on it.

Comment: Once the file is uploaded you should either move it, copy it, or set it to not delete temporary files (ew). The absolute file path is provided by either the temporary directory and the action's file name property, or by wherever you've moved/copied it to--since you *know* where you put it, problem solved.